# Design automation for Revit runner is crashing on its own

Tags: revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

We have been running a design automation app for over a year now and we get errors due to unexpected things happening in the revit files from time to time (stuff we didnt account for etc), but those errors are handled. However, now I have seen an increasing amount of errors that does not seem to be inflicted by our code.

Revit seems to be hard crashing in the middle of the workload. Please see part of the log:
An exception is thrown for an operation that we ran, but it is caught by our exception handler and the next file is started and logs look normal.
"Starting rfa..." is the new file.

However at 7:55 we have some kind of error and then the application exists with an error.

We have had this error a few times now.

[image]

Any thoughts on this except avoiding setting that?
We run batches of files with exception handling and if the batch fails like this it it messes with our failure handling logic when receiving the result.

Comment: Have you tried the [Local debugging tool](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-debug-revit-plugin-locally)? Is there no error when the same Addin code is run locally?

Have you tried using [adskDebug](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/using-argument-adskdebug-troubleshot-failure-job-design-automation)  and examined the failure journal?